# PowerPoint VBA search and delete paragraphs in Notes

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I have several PowerPoints with a great deal of text in the notes.   I need to search the note text and delete any paragraphs that start with "A."

Here is what I tried - but am getting type mismatch error

```
  Dim curSlide As Slide
  Dim curNotes As Shape
  Dim x As Long

  For Each curSlide In ActivePresentation.Slides
    Set curNotes = curSlide.NotesPage.Shapes(2).TextFrame.TextRange

    With curNotes.TextFrame.TextRange
        For x = 1 To Len(curNotes.TextFrame.TextRange)
            If Mid(curNotes.TextFrame.TextRange, x, 2) = "A." Then
                curNotes.TextFrame.TextRange.Paragraphs = ""
            End If
        Next x
    End With

  Next curSlide

End Sub
```

Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get a mismatch error whenever you try to assign data of a different type specified by your variable. This is happening in your code because you defined curNotes as type Shape and then tried to set that object variable to a different data type, TextRange. You are then trying to process the object TextRange as a string. You need to work on the .Text child of .TextRange The use of Mid is not checking the start of the string and finally, when you set the text to "", you are deleting all the text in the Note but that's not what you said you're trying to do.

This is the corrected code to delete only paragraphs starting with "A."

```
' PowerPoint VBA macro to delete all slide note paragraphs starting with the string "A."
' Rewritten by Jamie Garroch of youpresent.co.uk
Option Explicit

Sub DeleteNoteParagraphsStartingA()
  Dim curSlide As Slide
  Dim curNotes As TextRange
  Dim iPara As Long

  For Each curSlide In ActivePresentation.Slides
    Set curNotes = curSlide.NotesPage.Shapes(2).TextFrame.TextRange

    With curNotes
      ' Count backwards in any collection when deleting items from it
      For iPara = .Paragraphs.Count To 1 Step -1
        If Left(.Paragraphs(iPara), 2) = "A." Then
          .Paragraphs(iPara).Delete
          Debug.Print "Paragraph " & iPara & " deleted from notes pane on slide " & curSlide.SlideIndex
        End If
      Next
    End With

  Next curSlide
End Sub
```

Comment: Great! If it worked for you, please feel free to add a vote :-)

Comment: Hi user3264432. As I spent time to write a solution for you which you say works, please could you vote for my answer? Thank you.

Comment: I am very happy to - but not sure how.   I clicked on the "green check."    Let me know what else I can do to give you credit.